# Haskell - Number of occurencies of a Char in a String

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am writing a function in Haskell to count the occurencies of a Char value in a String, but getting an error with the pattern matching. Is there any way I could change the pattern matching to check if the 'xs' String's first value is 'a'?

```
howMany :: Char -> String -> Int
howMany a [] = 0
howMany a (a : xs) = 1 + howMany a xs
howMany a (x : xs) = 0 + howMany a xs
```

Comment: As an aside, `filter` already implements the recursion pattern being used here. `howMany a = length . filter (== a)`. Explicit recursion and pattern matching aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

All patterns should be *linear*: that means you can not use the same variable twice in the head of a function. Haskell does pattern matching, not *unification* like in Prolog. This is specified in [section *3.17.1 Patterns* of the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-590003.17.1):

> All **patterns must be linear** — **no variable** may **appear more than once**. For example, this definition is illegal:
>
> ```
> f (x,x) = x     -- ILLEGAL; x used twice in pattern
> ```

You thus should check if `x == a` with the help of a *guard*:

```
howMany :: Char -> String -> Int
howMany a [] = 0
howMany a (x : xs)
  | x == a = 1 + howMany a xs
  | otherwise = howMany a xs
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to solve this without using guards?

Comment: @PeterKiss: with an `if-then-else`, but that is basically the same. You need to work with `==` to check the equivalence of two items. You can not check if the patterns would unify.

Comment: @PéterKiss Yes, many other ways. There's `if-then-else` as suggested by Willem; there's also `fromEnum :: Bool -> Int` and using `case x == a of ...` and more. In the end, they all boil down to pattern matching on a `Bool`, though (even the guard shown here).

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, how would your code translate into using explicit pattern matching with `case`?

```
howMany :: a -> [a] -> Int
howMany a b = case b of
    []       -> 0                   -- case 1
    (a : xs) -> 1 + howMany a xs    -- case 2
    (x : xs) -> 0 + howMany a xs    -- case 3
```

The `a` in `-- case 2` is a completely new variable, fully independent of the outer `a` serving as a formal parameter to `howMany`. It could be named with any other name, like

```
howMany :: a -> [a] -> Int
howMany a b = case b of
    []       -> 0                   -- case 1
    (x : xs) -> 1 + howMany a xs    -- case 2
    (x : xs) -> 0 + howMany a xs    -- case 3
```

and now we see clearly what was true before as well -- that the cases 2 and 3 are one and the same.

But that is not what we intended. We wanted to differentiate between `x==a` case and its negation.

The solution is just to be explicit about our intentions:

```
howMany :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
howMany a b = case b of
    []       -> 0                   -- case 1
    (x : xs) 
      | x==a -> 1 + howMany a xs    -- case 2
    (x : xs) -> 0 + howMany a xs    -- case 3
```

The above can be further translated with lambda notation as

```
howMany :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
howMany = \a -> (\b -> case b of
    []       -> 0                   -- case 1
    (x : xs) 
      | x==a -> 1 + howMany a xs    -- case 2
    (x : xs) -> 0 + howMany a xs )  -- case 3
```

So this is why non-linear patterns are disallowed in Haskell -- because the arguments to a function are pattern matched *one by one*, and not in unison.

That's what *"matched, not unified"* technical remark in the other answer means. The *inner* lambda is a Haskell value in its own right, standing on its own. But if it were to differentiate on its argument variable name it would have to be made to act differently -- nay, to *be* different -- according to some other variable in some outer environment somewhere? That's just won't do.